# SD probability problem involving chi-square distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, chi-squared-test, standard-deviation, sample

Preparing for an exam in statistics, I have been pondering the following problem:

> Given that in country X 14% of people hold a university degree, find the probability that for a random sample of size 200 the standard deviation is less than 20.

Trying to compute this resulted in ridiculously high values for the chi-square-distribution.

Any input would be warmly welcomed.

Comment: I'm sure I'm misunderstanding this problem. Are you sure you don't mean "the number of people with a degree is less than 20?" This is a binary variable, I don't see how standard deviation would apply?

Comment: no, it's how I put it. If it was phrased like your problem, we could use the normal approximation to the binomial distribution.

Comment: OK, I'm still not sure I understand the question. What conditions would constitute a standard deviation of 20 on the sample? Would you be measuring the square root of 200*p*(1-p), where p is the percentage of people in the sample who hold a university degree and compare that number to 20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes on exams you just have to answer them literally as written.  It helps to explain and justify your interpretation.  In this case presumably the question refers to the university degree as coded with a binary ($0/1$) variable.  Let's assume it really does ask about samples with a standard deviation less than $20$.

There are just $201$ possible samples, parameterized by their total, $k$.  The mean of such a sample is $k/200$ and therefore its variance (without assuming any bias correction factor) is the average squared deviation from this mean, equal to

$$V(k) = \frac{1}{200}\left(k(1 - k/200)^2 + (200-k)(0 - k/200)^2\right) = k - k^2/200.\tag{1}$$

This attains its maximum when $k=100$, at which point it equals

$$V(100) = 100 - 100^2/200 = 50.$$

Since a standard deviation of $20$ corresponds to a variance of $20^2 = 400$, *it is certain that the standard deviation will be less than $20$*.  The answer, then, is $1$.

---

Using $1/199$ instead of $1/200$ as the factor in formula (1), to correct for bias, will not change this answer.